# Deadlock between UIImage drawInRect and UIApplication beginBackgroundTask

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, deadlock

I've got a deadlock in my iOS app between `UIImage drawInRect` on the main thread and `UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` on a background thread.  On the main thread, the stack looks like this:

> 0 semaphore_wait_drap
>
> 1 _dispatch_group_wait_slow
>
> 2 copyImageBlockSetJPEG
>
> 3 ImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetCallback
>
> 4 img_blocks_create
>
> 5 img_data_lock
>
> 6 CGSImageDataLock
>
> 7 ripc_AcquireImage
>
> 8 ripc_DrawImage
>
> 9 CGContextDrawImage
>
> 10 [UIImage drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:]
>
> 11 [UIImage scaleToSize:interpolationQuality:]

Frame 11 is a category method to scale an image.  Basically, begin an image drawing context, draw the image to that context at 0,0 with the desired size, and get an image from the context.

The stack on the background thread looks like this:

> 0 semaphore_wait_trap
>
> 1 dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow
>
> 2 _addBackgroundTask
>
> 3 [UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]

How on earth are these two things related enough to be blocked by the same lock?

UPDATE: When this happens, the app has a lot of thread conditions and semaphores being waited on.  Is there a limit to the number of active locks and conditions that can be active at one time on iOS?